AKS with application gateway - always 502
I followed ms and k8s tutorials and tried to configure ingress for 2 demo rest apis, with application gateway.
I hope to have chat-service at /chat and session-service at /session, but requests always end up as 502 bad gateway.
I tested my cluster with MS ingress demo app, and it worked. Looked the same as mine, except just 1 service.
...
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: session-service
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: session-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: session-service
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        app: scalable
      containers:
      - name: session-service-container
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        image: myacr.azurecr.io/scalable/session-service:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
        - name: REDIS
          value: "scalable-redis.default.svc.cluster.local"
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 1m
            memory: 128Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 30m
            memory: 512Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: session-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: session-service
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: chat-service
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: chat-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: chat-service
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        app: scalable
      containers:
      - name: chat-service-container
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        image: myacr.azurecr.io/scalable/chat-service:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
        - name: REDIS
          value: "scalable-redis.default.svc.cluster.local"
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 1m
            memory: 128Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 30m
            memory: 512Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: chat-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: chat-service
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: scalable-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: azure-application-gateway
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /chat
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: chat-service
            port: 
              number: 8080
      - path: /session
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: session-service
            port: 
              number: 8080

If i port-forward those pods to local and make requests, they are working fine.
What am I missing? health probes come up as "unhealthy", does that affect the routes?
$ kubectl get pods,svc,ingress
NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/chat-front-5647f964bf-kt86z        1/1     Running   0          12h
pod/chat-front-5647f964bf-vkxhg        1/1     Running   0          12h
pod/chat-service-77cc84cf45-5ns8q      1/1     Running   0          12h
pod/chat-service-77cc84cf45-lqf6g      1/1     Running   0          12h
pod/scalable-redis-9f69d9f96-v7d69     1/1     Running   0          12h
pod/session-service-5b66cddcbf-sfmbg   1/1     Running   0          12h
pod/session-service-5b66cddcbf-z9v4h   1/1     Running   0          12h

NAME                      TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)        AGE
service/chat-front-lb     LoadBalancer   10.0.146.62    20.250.xxx.yyy   80:31316/TCP   12h
service/chat-service      ClusterIP      10.0.166.152   <none>           8080/TCP       12h
service/kubernetes        ClusterIP      10.0.0.1       <none>           443/TCP        12h
service/scalable-redis    ClusterIP      10.0.90.162    <none>           6379/TCP       12h
service/session-service   ClusterIP      10.0.55.242    <none>           8080/TCP       12h

NAME                                         CLASS                       HOSTS   ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
ingress.networking.k8s.io/scalable-ingress   azure-application-gateway   *       4.226.xxx.yyy   80      12h


Argh, it was about the probes. the automatic configuration was messed up.
[edit]
I had two things going wrong here:
a) the application gateway probes must return "healthy" for traffic to be sent to that backend. I had custom health endpoints, but with that yaml the probes were configured to ping the wrong address (needed to specify "/chat/health" instead of just "/chat" since my root was not responding anything
b) my services has routes like "/login", but when they go through prefix paths, the service receives calls to "/session/login" and there is no endpoint. I needed rewrite rules to strip out the path prefixes. Something like "if server variable uri_path is /session/(.+) then set url path to /{var_uri_path_1}"
then everything worked. after that i moved to having subdomains for each api, so I dont need to do path rewrites

Could you update your answer in details what you modified and fixed the issue? Helps anyone who is having similar issue reference your answer on SO

I added details, thanks for pointing that out
